# Absolutely positioned menu in footer - wrong margin in Opera

Tags: opera

http://www.crtaci.info/

I have some absolutely positioned menu in footer.

Tested in FF 3.5.3, Safari, IE8, Chrome... But in Opera I'm getting a big gap below that menu in the footer.

[image]

ps title is margin problem, because I *think* it is some margin issue... :)

Comment: Can you show the css  and html that is used, so that we can see what might be going on?

Comment: Also, which version of Opera are you testing on?

Comment: Hi. Is there any specific reason why you have put div#footer_menu outside div#footer. Regards

Comment: Well use firebug/web developer, or some other plugin. Its much easier for you to watch the entire site structure. :)

Regarding #footer_menu, i want that to be absolutly positioned at bottom. Problem is that i have some pages that dont have some big height, so if i put it in normal dom flow #footer_menu is not at bottom of the screen. And i needed to put it outside wrapper so it would be relative to body, if i put it inside its relative to some other dom element because position:relative is used pretty much inside my wrapper.

Im testing it on latest verion of opera - ver 10 bulid 1750

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opera has too small a market share for me to design specifically for it, but this page has a solution that should work, but it doesn't work on Opera when you resize.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/html-css-footer/

You may want to look at what the author does, and see if you can understand what you are doing differently.

Comment: Hi. The example (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/html-css-footer/) works fine in Opera 10 even when resized. Regards

Comment: Just going by what was written in the article. I just realized that I don't have Opera on this laptop, so I couldn't test it. I am installing it now. :)

Comment: Hmm this looks kinda interesting. He is puting min-height:100% on content... :) I will test this, and if i cant get it to work, i will just put that #footer_menu inside footer, so it has normal dom flow, not absolutly positioning, after all its only few pages that have small height...

Comment: Yes, the article is very interesting, I think using #footer_spacer in combination with #content and #footer will help. As the footer behaves perfectly in Opera for the article's example. Regards